# Can someone help me configure Tidy2 for Notepad++

Tags: html, notepad++, code-cleanup, tidy

**This question is about: HTML Cleanup using Tidy2 for Notepad++**

I guys! I tried looking up Tidy Configuration on here for HTML, and it seems that people are using it to tidy up code in a different program language so I wasn't able to answer my own question.

Well, I generally edit sections of web pages, and most of the time it looks absolutely terrible so I use tidy to clean it up for me. Because I edit sections, I have no use for the base HTML setup (`<html><head><title></head><body></body></html>`). I have read that there is a way around this using a show-body-only attribute, but there isn't really any direction of how to implement it. I tried placing show-body-only:true at the end of the configuration file, however it still prints out all the extra junk that it usually does.

How do I implement this in Notepad++? Does it matter where I place the attribute at the end of the file? Am I doing this correctly, and it just isn't working?

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is my configuration file:

```
    indent: auto
    indent-spaces: 4
    wrap: 132
    markup: yes
    output-xml: yes
    input-xml: no
    numeric-entities: yes
    quote-marks: yes
    quote-nbsp: yes
    quote-ampersand: no
    break-before-br: no
    uppercase-tags: no
    uppercase-attributes: no
    new-inline-tags: cfif, cfelse, math, mroot, 
        mrow, mi, mn, mo, msqrt, mfrac, msubsup, munderover,
        munder, mover, mmultiscripts, msup, msub, mtext,
        mprescripts, mtable, mtr, mtd, mth
    new-blocklevel-tags: cfoutput, cfquery
    new-empty-tags: cfelse
    show-body-only: true
```

Answer (score 1):

just thought that I'd update this and say that I found an answer after too much messing around.
It turns out that "output-xml: yes" was interfering with the "show-body-only:yes" attribute.

I hope that this helps someone else, so here is the code, still deletes empty tags and all that good stuff, but it won't print out any of that extra html junk!

```
indent: yes
indent-spaces: 4
wrap: 132
markup: yes
clean: yes
show-body-only:yes
vertical-space: no
sort-attributes: alpha
add-xml-space: no
output-xml: no
input-xml: no
numeric-entities: yes
quote-marks: yes
quote-nbsp: yes
quote-ampersand: no
break-before-br: no
uppercase-tags: no
uppercase-attributes: no
new-inline-tags: cfif, cfelse, math, mroot, 
  mrow, mi, mn, mo, msqrt, mfrac, msubsup, munderover,
  munder, mover, mmultiscripts, msup, msub, mtext,
  mprescripts, mtable, mtr, mtd, mth
new-blocklevel-tags: cfoutput, cfquery
new-empty-tags: cfelse
```